# How to preform the Matlab function "pspectrum" in Python (possibly with numpy)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, signal-processing

I would like to analyze a few seconds of sound and visually see the power of each frequency used throughout the sound. In matlab I can use the function pspectrum and get something that looks like

[this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/signal/win64/TimeFrequencyAnalysisExample_04.png)

Is there a way to do that in python using numpy or a similar library?

Comment: In Matlab I've used `spectrogram` for that in the past (`pspectrum` is a very recent function). So Python's [`scipy.signal.spectrogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html) looks promising

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to perform spectrogram in python. First, by using scipy library and second by using matplotlib library. The scipy library is most commonly used because whole scipy library is for signal processing. Moreover, matplotlib spectrogram function is having more features than that of scipy.

I would say to go with matpoltlib function because matplotlib library is specially for visualization. Kindly, find the link for both library documentation.

Installing python library for spectrum:
1.) scipy library = pip install scipy (Documentation -https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.spectrogram.html)

2.) matplotlib library = pip install matplotlib (Documentation-https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.specgram.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.specgram)

Free to ask more question related to this topic. Good luck!